# security of server side scripts behind website

Tags: security

I'm new to website development and have a web 101 question but I really got confused about. Maybe it is too simple that I cannot find an answer via internet search. I wonder so if I developed a simple website with some basic HTML, CSS, but also some python scripts that I use to process user input data. Is there a way to let the outside user be able to execute the scripts so that the website can give them the results, however restrict the scripts from being accessed and read (via ftp kinda thing) directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the web-server as owner and permissions to 700, and only the web server will be able to execute them.